# Is it possible for a field name to have different datatype in mapping of another type in elastic search 2.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have two types in elastic search: users, tasks.

1. The mapping in users have field u_id whose type is integer.
2. The mapping in tasks have field u_id whose type is string.

I am getting this error while creating index:

```
mapper_parsing_exception: Failed to parse mapping [tasks]: mapper [u_id] 
cannot be changed from type [int] to [string]
```

It seems like elastic search do not allow to different types to have same field name with different types. Am i correct with this or not.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you have 2 different indexes, and you for sure can have different mapping in them.

This error tells you that you cannot change already created mapping in existing index 'tasks'. More [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html)

> Updating existing mappings
>
> Other than where documented, existing type and field mappings cannot be 
>   updated. Changing the mapping would mean invalidating already indexed 
>   documents. Instead, you should create a new index with the correct 
>   mappings and reindex your data into that index.

More about mapping update [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings)

In this situation you can:

1. easy way - delete index 'type' and create it again with new mapping.
2. More complex way - is to use [_reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/docs-reindex.html) and reindex ypur data to new index with correct mapping type.